# Can "harsh" be used as a noun?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I came across the word "harsh" used as a noun today. For example:

> I consistently showed up late to work, which turned out to be a harsh on my ambitions.

The above example is very recent (from 2014), US English.

I looked up the word "harsh" in three different dictionaries and not one had the word listed as a noun. They all categorized "harsh" as an adjective. The noun form is "harshness."

Comment: It could be a misprint, with an unintended indefinite article creeping in.

Comment: Remember that dictionaries just follow usage—not the other way around. If people start to use it as a noun, then it will be recognized as one (ugly though it be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use you encountered is a nominalization of the slang use of 'harsh' as a verb. A version of a notorious example of the use is

> Getting stopped by the police really harshed my buzz, man.

Both the nominalization and the verb are slang uses, which I've encountered in the wild.

The slang verbal sense is defined in Collins:

> **harsh**
>   ....
>   Verb
>   3. (transitive) ( slang) to cause (a state of elation) to be diminished or ended (esp in the phrases harsh someone's mellow and harsh someone's buzz).

[harsh. Dictionary.com. Collins English Dictionary - Complete & Unabridged 10th Edition. HarperCollins Publishers. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/harsh (accessed: November 24, 2015).]

Comment: Your answer mirrors mine, but you win for discovering the slang usage of "harsh" in a reputable dictionary! But why is the definition only present in the British dictionary and not the American dictionary? The idiom comes from American slang.

Comment: @Kyle I didn't see your answer until after I posted mine, or I probably would've discarded mine and simply commented about the appearance in Collins. As it stood, though, I felt mine added something substantial, so I left it. I remembered "man, you're harshin' my buzz" and "puttin' the harsh on me" from somebody saying them to me in the seventies, and ran a search--that's when Collins turned up. I don't know why it's in the British dictionary...maybe they felt that bit of Americana needed explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could, but it's in very poor taste.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence you quote - would it be of fairly recent vintage?

The use of "harsh" as a noun in that sentence has a certain modern ring to it, but to me it is a new formulation and sounds self-consciously edgy or simply new-speak.  But for the writer, it might be reasonably common usage.

*I consistently showed up late to work, which turned out to harsh my mellow.*

That is a completely inappropriate use of harsh, and the whole phrase, of course. If I understand the term correctly, going to work **early** would be more likely to "harsh my mellow".

Comment: The sentence is from last year, 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Upon more research, I suspect that this usage of "harsh" stems from the informal expression, "to harsh one's mellow." This usage of "harsh" is nonstandard as well, as no dictionary categorizes "harsh" as a verb.

I could not find the meaning of this idiom on any reputable website, but I did find the following explantation on [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=harshing%20my%20mellow&defid=1117869):

> Bringing down my good mood.

The expression was apparently not well-known enough to qualify for a page on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:harsh_one%27s_mellow). However, before the page was deleted from Wikitionary, a more substantial definition existed:

> 1. (idiomatic) To annoy or irritate; to bother.
> 2. To make someone feel bad emotionally. "The fact that her bike was stolen totally harshed her mellow"
> 3. Disturbing someone otherwise in a state of calm (some drug connotations)
> 4. To get on one's nerves.

The etymology of "harshing my mellow" is unclear. It was the title of a [1991 noise rock album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harshing_My_Mellow). According to a [random commenter](http://makingheadsortailsofidioms.com/2009/03/17/harsh-my-mellow/#comment-98) on a blog, the album title was not the first time this phrase was used:

> My friends and I were using “don’t harsh on my mellow” back in the early ’80’s. I’d like to say it was a Cheech and Chong album quote, but I can’t find reference and I don’t have copies. It was common in the West Coast stoner lexicon of that era (and I lived in Idaho).

[This website](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-har2.htm) writes

> It became more widely known in 1997 when it turned up in The Online Adventures of Ozzie the Elf on ABC television.

The owner of the ["Don't Harsh My Mellow" trademark](http://www.dontharshmymellow.com/AboutUs.asp), a man named Jack, claims he invented the phrase:

> The phrase Don't Harsh My Mellow® was first used by Jack at a Grateful Dead Show (aka concert) in 1989.

But [this site](http://www.inthe70s.com/generated/terms.shtml) says the idiom dates back to the 1970s.

I could not find any evidence of this online, but I reckon that the usage of "harsh" as a noun is the shortened version of this idiom. If this is accurate, then the example sentence in my original post basically means

> I consistently showed up late to work, which turned out to harsh my mellow.